# How to change EditText of Holo theme?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme

Is there a way to change the edittext style of the Hole theme? I don't want the default padding, neither the blue/grey line underneath. I just want a plain EditText I can put in a box with a hint. Thanks!

Comment: Create custom Theme. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use any texture you want for your `EditText` view. Just pick something on the web and set it as the background of your `EditText`.

**Example:**

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etlsPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/login_scr_field"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/my_darker_gray" />
```

Comment: never act like this. use styles instead.

Comment: `<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etlsPassword"
        android:style="@style/password_box"/>`
looks much more elegant. Rest of code will be in that style. And you don't need to change every control if you will want to change appearance later.